# Why does GetCategoriesCall return 0 categories?

Tags: c#, .net, ebay-api

I'm trying to get all root categories for eBay Germany using the eBay .Net SDK. I have this code:

```
var rootCategoriesCall = new GetCategoriesCall(apiContext);
rootCategoriesCall.Site = SiteCodeType.Germany;
rootCategoriesCall.LevelLimit = 1;
var categories = rootCategoriesCall.GetCategories().Cast<CategoryType>();
```

The call appears to be executed (there is the usual delay that accompanies eBay API calls) and it does not throw an error, yet I get 0 categories. Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior and how to fix it?

Note that I use a Sandbox token. As for the `rootCategoriesCall.LevelLimit = 1;` line. [This site](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GetCategories.html) was suggesting it as a way of getting only the root categories.

P.S. I also tried setting `CategorySiteID` instead of `Site` and not setting it at all (it defaults to eBay US), but the result was the same.

Comment: This doesn't work? http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2012/06/25/retrieving-a-list-of-ebay-categories-using-the-.net-sdk.aspx

Comment: @DavidG I've seen this page before, but I decided to compare their code with mine one more time. It appears that explicitly adding `rootCategoriesCall.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);` to my code makes it actually work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Feels a bit cheeky of me to use that as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about why it is required, but it appears that I explicitly need to set `DetailLevel`. If I change my call to:

```
var rootCategoriesCall = new GetCategoriesCall(apiContext);
rootCategoriesCall.Site = SiteCodeType.Germany;
rootCategoriesCall.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll);
rootCategoriesCall.LevelLimit = 1;
var categories = rootCategoriesCall.GetCategories().Cast<CategoryType>();
```

I do get the root categories.

Comment: .Site is to manually override the site defined in the api context. you need to use the specific category id property for this call.

Comment: Also, if you don't supply a category site id, it defaults to the id defined in the api context